# Conditional IN Statement to be used inside Postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I am working on Postgres and I have two tables vehicles and vehicles_flag. There are no relations between the two tables and hence we can not join two tables to fetch the required data.
The table structure is below (vehicle_flag table may not contain all the id present in the vehicle table) :

[Table structure] [image]

I am writing a function that will accept multiple input parameters. I have to select vehicle id from the vehicle_flag table only if the flag value is true: otherwise, I have to ignore the vehicel_flag table. My aim is to achieve something like this, but turns out the case statement expects scaler output:

```
select count(id) from vehicles
where 
vehicles.id in (case
when @hasbluetooth =1 then (select distinct id from vehicle_flags where flag='bluetooth' and       value = '1')
else
(select distinct id from vehicles)
end)

and

vehicles.id in (case
when @hasac =1 then (select distinct id from vehicle_flags where flag='ac' and value = '1')
else
(select distinct id from vehicles)
end)
```

Kindly suggest any solution to achieve this.

Comment: You say there is no relation between the tables.  Then you specify that `id` is precisely such a relationship.  I'm confused.

Comment: Hello @GordonLinoff Yes there is vehicle id in both the tables. I want to get the total count of vehicles(distinct vehicle id)  based on some conditions but if I do vehicles left join vehicles_flags on vehicles.id = vehicles_flags.id, then I get multiple counts for one vehicle id. That's why I don't want to join both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want:

```
select v.*
from vehicle v
left join vehicle_flags vf on vf.id = v.id
group by v.id
having
    (@hasbluetooth = 0 or bool_or(vf.flag = 'bluetooth' and vf.value = 1)
    and (@hasac = 0 or bool_or(vf.flag = 'ac' and vf.value = 1)
```